# Can't uninstall protractor in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, protractor

I wish to uninstall protractor because, after successfully installing version 5.4.1, `protractor --version` still shows 5.3.2. The idea is to completely remove protractor from my computer.
I've tried `sudo npm uninstall -g protractor` and the result I get is: `up to date in 0.042s`. When I run `protractor --version` I get 5.3.2 again.
Is there another command that can remove protractor from ubuntu?

Also, please, have in mind I must install it again in the future, and I'd skip a solution to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131251/cannot-install-npm-after-uninstalling-npm-in-ubuntu-16-04) since I'm a noob and probably won't be able to deal with the variations of that problem

Comment: I guess you installed protractor 5.3.2 in your Ubuntu box and exposed it into `$PATH` environment.  But you didn't expose protractor 5.4.1 into `$PATH`.execute `type -a protractor` this will list all available `protractor` in `$PATH` environment and compare them to the value of `$PATH` to find out where the others protractor installed.  Then you can choose to delete them

Answer (score 0):

You installed protractor 5.3.2 in your Ubuntu box and exposed it into `$PATH` environment.

But you didn't expose protractor 5.4.1 into `$PATH`. That's why you always get 5.3.2 by `protractor --version` no matter you install/uninstall protractor 5.4.1

Remove 5.3.2 from `$PATH`, then add 5.4.1 into `$PATH` should fix your problem.